# Java processbuilder child processes continue after exit

Tags: java, daemon, processbuilder

I'm working on an auto-update script that should be able to restart the daemon once it completes.

I'm currently trying this:

```
    final ArrayList<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
    String initScriptPath = Config.GetStringWithDefault("init_script", "/etc/init.d/my-daemon");
    command.add("/bin/bash");
    command.add("-c");
    command.add("'" + initScriptPath + " restart'");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String c : command) {
        sb.append(c).append(" ");
    }
    Log.write(LogPriority.DEBUG, "Attempting restart with: " + sb.toString());

    final ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);

    builder.start();

    // Wait for a couple of seconds
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    System.exit(0);
```

However the System.exit seems to stop the restart? It does actually stop, but does not start again.

Comment: so does the question here amount to: "Does system.exit kill child processes"?

Comment: @NathanHughes Yes, I added that to the title, makes more sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should definitely wait for your process to complete before exiting:

```
final ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
final Process process = builder.start();
final int processStatus = process.waitFor();
```

And you should consume the output stream of the process, as it can cause the process to block if the output buffer becomes full. Not sure if this is applicable to your scenario but its a best practice in any case:

```
String line = null;
final BufferedReader reader =
    new InputStreamReader (process.getInputStream());
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   // Ignore line, or do something with it
}
```

You can also use a library like [Apache IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#readLines%28java.io.InputStream%29) for the last part.

Comment: also make sure that you read the process' inputstream and errorstream, otherwise the process may hang.

Comment: Still does not work. I currently have everything above + process.getInputStream() and process.getOutputStream(). Nothing seems to actually work. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Define doesn't work? The process is terminating prematurely? It doesn't complete? Are you consuming the output stream of the process?

Comment: The "best" result I get is that the main process stops, but doesn't start. I might have a clue that it has got something to do with the init script that keeps track of the PID and refuses to start if there's still an active process. I rewrote the restart script to rebuild the java -jar JARPATH command and all the parameters. This works now. Thank you all for your time :)

As I think this answer is actually the best when not using my init script I'll accept it as answer. It does make sense.

Comment: `process.getOutputStream()` looks wrong. That is the stream for writing to the process (stdin).